# What's the proper statement I should say when someone keep canceling the meetings?

Tags: expressions

have a friend I want to meet up with ; every time I ask her to meet up we scheduled a meeting then she don't show up or cancel the meeting a day before the meeting. Last week she said we going to meet up on Thursday then she canceled the meeting . I know sometimes people get busy or things happen but she keep  repeat it over and over again

. Is there an expression in the English language you could use to show your anger when some one cancel a meeting? 
Should I say 
Never mind or 
Just forget it 
Or should i use a different expression 
What is the best statement I should say to show my  anger with out  using profanity ?

Comment: A slang term for this kind of person is *flaky*.

Answer (score 2):

I would ask, “Are you serious [about wanting to meet me]? 
Or are you just ***[putting me off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put%20off)?”***

> **put off**:
>
> - to hold back to a later time
> - to induce to wait <*put* the bill collector *off*>
> - to rid oneself of

“Are you giving me the ***[runaround](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/runaround)?”***

> deceptive or delaying action, especially in response to a request